# "Smoothed" should be "Weekly" on "Access To Site Analytics" help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

Just a quick (very low sev) request to update the help centre text.

---

The [help/privileges/site-analytics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) page in the Help Centre has the following image:

[image: Smoothed]

And a sentence that explains "Smoothed":

> Selecting the "Smoothed" checkbox will change the data points to per
>   week.

This has been updated to "Weekly" in the Site Analytics page now:

[image]

I'm guessing the help just needs updating to match.

Answer (score 2):

Since animuson put in the shiny [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag and the help center has been updated, I would say that it has been updated and correctly fixed.

> Selecting the "Weekly" checkbox will change the data points to per week.